# Do 'ordinary' Gazans have firearms (much)?

Tags: guns, gaza, hamas

In Afghanistan, it was a bit of problem when raiding homes etc., because many Afghans [had](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-afghanistan-guns-idINBRE8BH00Y20121218) firearms, so just finding a hidden AK-47 in someone's home wasn't a clear indicator if he was Taliban or not. (And yes, it was illegal to own such, and made owners subject to arrest by the Western-supported gov't. And yeah, RFERL [reported](https://www.rferl.org/a/this-afghan-girl-watched-the-taliban-execute-her-parents-then-she-picked-up-an-ak-47-and-killed-two-militants-herself-/30741131.html) such weapons even being used against the Taliban, when they conducted raids.)

I'm curious how is the guns situation in Gaza. Do 'ordinary' Gazans have firearms much, legal or otherwise? Or did Hamas manage to exercise tight control in this regard?

Comment: Firearms?  Or *automatic* assault rifles/military-level gear?  Heck, even in SecondAmendmentLand™️, a real, auto-capable, AK47 would raise a few eyebrows.

Comment: FWTW, RFERL doesn't mention that, but the Taliban later denied that those attackers killed by Gul were actually Taliban https://www.news24.com/news24/world/news/afghan-girl-who-killed-taliban-gunmen-ready-to-fight-again-20200722

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica I'm no arms expert, but is it that different to the AR-15 that every american in the bible belt owns? Or it would raise eyebrows because of being a soviet, rather than american, design?

Comment: @Rekesoft The difference is in the "auto capable", but bump stocks can actually add that as an add-on to those AR-15s as well.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава Auto-capable means continuous fire? That may be the reason, though automatic fire is for enemy suppression, not for killing. You spray a rain of bullets over some area to make the enemy duck for cover; however, aiming with an automatic rifle is way more difficult. After the first shot only God knows where the rest of bullets go and you empty your magazine in no time. **ItalianPhilosophers4Monica** may be right that, since automatic weapons are forbidden, they are looked with suspicion, even if a semi-automatic rifle is actually far more lethal in most cases.

Comment: @Rekesoft You certainly *are* no expert, that's for sure.  AR-15 or AK-47 doesn't matter.  The *auto* part of it does:  full auto guns are illegal in the US.  Yes, you can modify a neutered gun back to that capability.  [But it's also illegal](https://giffords.org/lawcenter/gun-laws/policy-areas/hardware-ammunition/machine-guns-50-caliber).  Hard to believe, to oppress poor Americans that much, eh?

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica As I answered to Vladimir above, then it is just a matter of being "illegal" in the USA. If two guys enter at two different crowded McDonalds and start shooting everyone there, I'd bet for the one with the semi-auto, hands down. The one with the autofiring would just "RA-TA-TA-TA-TA" and suddenly he's out of ammo, most of his bullets on the ceiling. But since they're illegal, I guess they can rise some eyebrows. Here in the sane part of the world, both would do.

Comment: @Rekesoft which is why many assault rifles have 3 settings.  semi-auto (single shot), burst mode, full auto.  #2 and #3 are both illegal.  Your hypothetical McD crowd is specifically where full auto mode might be useful, to clear the room (it generally isn't thought so because guns lose accuracy on auto and it burns ammo).  Don't give up your day job to become a firearms instructor, "RA-TA-TA-TA-TA".

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica I wonder why you have felt the need to sneer twice at my lack of knowledge of firearms just to say that, indeed, I am right. It must be sad emigrating from France to Canada while not only not losing the stereotypical french rudeness, but to add american arrogance as top of the cake.

Comment: @Rekesoft Because you felt you had to lecture about the AK-47 Soviet bit and a supposed bias about that.  I am sure there are plenty of AK-47s in the US.  And your exchanges with me in the past haven't been all that friendly, so no need to act all innocently hurt.  I am happy keeping my, very un-Canadian, snark, yes.

Comment: FWIW, Afghanistan has been in a hotter or cooler shooting war, almost continuously, for more than four decades. Gaza has been at odds with Israel for even longer, but only a very small percentage of that time period has been an actual live shooting war.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Just to add to pedantic complexity, full auto is not strictly illegal in the US. Some are grandfathered in and others require licensing. But the point goes that semi-auto, one bullet per pull of trigger, is legal. Anything that allows more than 1 bullet per trigger pull is strictly regulated. And yes, there are huge numbers of AK-47's in the US. However, the vast majority of those are specially made for US import without the full-auto or burst selections. As for Canada, if you pin the magazines to 5 rounds, most of the same guns as in the US are allowed as well.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica "A supposed bias about AK-47"? Read the question again, please, which is, I remind you, about how many firearms do Gazans own. Read your first comment again, and please explain to those of us who don't masturbate with "Small arms" magazine in one hand, why did you think your remark about AK-47s, or things that make americans raise an eyebrow (such as atheism, universal healthcare or women sunbathing topless at european beaches) had _ANYTHING_ to do with the question actually asked? Because for those without a paraphilia on weapons, it looks pointless.

Comment: @Rekesoft Simples.  Someone who owns say a revolver or a hunting rifle *may* not be all that highly on the radar of an IDF search team, IMHO.  (this Q was - i think motivated by an rather dubious claim on another answer)  Someone with an AK would definitely be.  It's not rocket science and that's why I asked fizz to clarify what type of firearms he was asking about.  Of course, you had to get all snippy and political, as you usually do.  The masturbation bit shows exactly how clever you are.  The type of guns owned by say Afghans or Europeans are very different in this context.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosphers4Monica Good Lord forbids going political on politics.stackexchange! Yes, I see why a gun lover would consider a revolver or a hunting rifle "not even a gun". For the rest of the world, the definition of gun is clear, and goes from a Derringer to the 380mm main cannon of a WWII battleship. And I can assure you that it does not go below the radar of an IDF search tearm. Not in a country where terrorist attacks are being carried with kitchen knives, or where waving palestinian flags is a serious crime that can land you in jail.

Comment: I was only stating this in the context of that other answer, which claimed having an AK in Gaza was justified for Joe Average non-combatant because of the food shortages.  I don't disagree even a handgun probably gets you in trouble, but an AK would be an order of magnitude worse.  But look at you.  After getting all whiny about me making fun of your gun knowledge, you graduate to masturbation and WW2 battleships.  Do grow up.  FWIW I don't support private gun ownership much and believe Canada has too many guns.  Ppl can go shoot at gun ranges and leave their guns there far as I am concerned.

Comment: Gazans do not have many weapons, They just have rocks. israel takes their weapons just as they take their land. Gazans need weapons

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Ordinary" Palestinians have a low firearm ownership rate by global standards, and a majority of all guns in Gaza and the West Bank combined (the finest level of detail available) are government owned. The numbers below aren't broken down between the West Bank and Gaza.

I suspect, but don't know, that private gun ownership is lower in Gaza (whose imports of firearms are more easily interdicted by the Israeli government) than in the West Bank. Also, gun ownership globally tends to be higher in rural areas like most of the West Bank, and lower in densely populated urban areas, like most of the people in the Gaza Strip. For reference purposes, there are about 2.3 million people outside Israeli settlements in the West Bank, and about 1.8 million people in the Gaza Strip. I suspect that significantly less than 40% of privately owned guns in the West Bank and Gaza are in Gaza.

[As of 2017](https://www.gunpolicy.org/firearms/region/palestine): The estimated total number of guns (both licit and illicit) held by civilians in Palestine is 56,000 (probably significantly less than 22,000 in Gaza). In a comparison to the number of privately owned guns in 206 countries, Palestine ranked at No. 159.

The estimated rate of private gun ownership (both licit and illicit) per 100 people in Palestine is 1.10. This private gun ownership rate is probably lower in Gaza. In a comparison to the rate of privately owned guns per 100 people in 206 countries, Palestine ranked at No. 167. By comparison, [40% of Americans](https://www.pewresearch.org/short-reads/2023/09/13/key-facts-about-americans-and-guns/#:%7E:text=About%20a%20third%20of%20adults,conducted%20in%202021%20and%202017.) live in a household with civilian firearms (that rises to 58% in the rural U.S.).

The defense forces of Palestine are reported to have 44,410 firearms. Police in Palestine are reported to have 33,000 firearms.

It isn't manifestly obvious that some guns owned by "civilians" aren't actually owned by people affiliated with armed terrorist groups, as opposed to owning firearms merely for private self-defense.

I couldn't find any reliable data on the types of guns owned by civilian Palestinians.

This low rate of private gun ownership is mostly due to the fact that there are essentially no legally recognized small arms manufacturers in the West Bank or Gaza, and imports of small arms and ammunitions are tightly regulated by Israel (mostly for government use) to about $140,000 per year of small arms and ammunition imports. Israeli import regulation is Gaza is particularly effective since it is basically a walled city with Israel's navy tightly controlling maritime trade with Gaza.

The Hamas regime does regulate firearms, but external limitations on the importation of firearms there imposed by Israel is the bigger factor. Another factor, which also impacts illicit small arms imports, is that the people of Gaza aren't affluent. The only other places in the world outside of Africa that are comparably poor (judged by demographic estimates that escape the complications of factors like currency exchange rates) are war torn Yemen and Afghanistan.

Hamas can have the arsenal that it does (which still isn't impressive by international military standards) only with illicit arms supplied on a subsidized basis to it by Iran, or facilitated by Iran.

Comment: For comparison, the same source put Afghanistan (2017) at 12.52 guns per 100 people, so about 10 times more density than for Palestine. They put the US at 120.5.

Comment: @Fizz That puts US private gun ownership at over 100x Palestine's private gun ownership.

Comment: _"whose imports of firearms are more easily interdicted by the Israeli government"_ - they still managed to sneak thousands of rockets; I guess firearms are even easier. This may not translate to "ordinary Gazans" directly, but I strongly suspect the estimation can easily be an order of magnitude off.

Comment: @Zeus The availability of large quantities of guns to Hamas troops does not mean Hamas, a dictatorship, remember, would relish the widespread availability of guns to the populace.  Ugh, I feel dirty saying this, I almost sound like a Second Amendment nutter.

Comment: @Zeus We know, as a matter of certainty, that it is possible to smuggle rockets and small arms into both the West Bank and Gaza. This does nothing, however, to alter to conclusion that it is easier to smuggle arms into the West Bank (e.g., over a much less thinly patrolled and enforced border with Jordan) than it is to smuggle arms into Gaza. This is all that the quoted language is saying. Also, import controls are the reason that Hamas has, e.g., no tanks, no armored vehicles, no self-propelled howitzers, no purpose built anti-aircraft guns, no advanced radar, and no military aircraft.

Comment: @ohwilleke, what?? Have you seen this border? There is a certain river there, and a relatively wide valley. No tunnels can be built there. Israel fully controls the valley and the road that goes there (which is even open to civilians). Effectively, the West Bank has no border with Jordan. In contrast, nearly everything is smuggled to Gaza through the border with Egypt, which Israel doesn't control. Few rockets could be smuggled to the West Bank, in contrast to Gaza. No, I'm not convinced in these numbers at all.

Comment: @Zeus The West Bank absolutely has a border with Jordan that is quite long. https://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-54116567 The narrow Gaza border with Egypt has two gates in a big wall, both controlled by Israel.

Comment: @Italian, I said just that. My objections are mostly the total numbers, which are likely way off, as well as the distribution between WB/Gaza, which is naively taken as roughly the population.

Comment: @ohwilleke, That's formality (which doesn't even have proper legal status). The reality is quite a bit [more complicated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:West_Bank_Access_Restrictions_June_2020.pdf). Effectively, WB has no access to the Jordan valley (without going through check points). In contrast, from the Israeli side, one could drive all along the border to the Dead Sea without even being checked (don't know right now, but recently so). In Gaza, smuggling mostly happens through the tunnels under the border, not through the official gates, of course.